# CodeIgniter 3.x.x + WireDesignz HMVC - Call to a member function core_template() on null

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc

I downloaded HMVC files from here and set up my CI 3 installation using these file

1. Place the MX folder in application/third_party folder
2. Place the files in application/core MY_Loader & MY_Router
3. Created a folder module in /application.
4. Inside module created welcome/controller and welcome/view
5. In welcome/controller I copied the default welcome controller and in
   welcome/view welcome_message.
6. Then I created a Template Module with and added below code in it
7. Then I created module for home, here is how my folder structure looks like

   ```
   class Template extends MY_Controller {

       public function __contruct(){

           parent:: __contruct();

       }

       public function core_template($data = null)
       {   
           //$data  = new stdClass(); 
           //$data->content  = 'home/home_v'; 
           $this->load->view('template/core_template_v', $data);
       }

       public function dashboard_template($data = '')
       {   
           //$data  = new stdClass();
           $this->load->view('template/dashboard_template_v', $data);
       }
   }
   ```

   Folder Structure

   ```
   application
   modules
    template
      controllers
        Template.php
      models
      views
        core_template_v.php
     Home
      controllers
         Home.php
      models
      views
   ```

   ## home_v.php

   ```
   Home.php // Controller

   class Home extends MY_Controller {

       public function __construct(){

          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->module('Template');
       } 

       public function index()
       {
           $data  = new stdClass();
           $data->content  = 'home/home_v';
           //$this->slice->view('welcome/welcome', $data);
           //print_r($data);
           $this->template->core_template($data);
       }

   }

   ============================================

   /* load the MX_Controller class */
   require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Controller.php";

   class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

       public function __construct(){

           parent::__construct();

           $this->load->module('Template');
       }
   }
   ```

   I am getting this error:

   ```
   An uncaught Exception was encountered
   Type: Error

   Message: Call to a member function core_template() on null

   Filename: */modules/home/controllers/Home.php

   Line Number: 18

   Backtrace:

   File: /*/public_html/index.php
   Line: 315
   Function: require_once
   ```

It is working perfectly fine on my local server but when I upload the code to my hosting its throwing this error.

Comment: What was the fix?

Comment: I had to create all templates in core view folder and then call the functions from a library helper I created named as 'Template'